# Convert pandas dataframe into a list of unique tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

What is the most efficient way to convert a pandas dataframe into a list of unique tuple?
In the code below I am trying to extract a list of tuples containing all the unique `PostalCode` and `Age`.

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Sequence, Tuple

import pandas as pd

data = [["tom", 10, "ab 11"], ["nick", 14, "ab 22"], ["juli", 10, "ab 11"]]
people = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Age", "PostalCode"])

subset = pd.unique(people[["PostalCode", "Age"]].values.ravel())

# This produce an error
output = list(subset.itertuples(index=False))

# Expected output
# [('ab 11', 10), ('ab 22', 14)]
```

Comment: `ab 11` and `ab 22` are PostalCodes but you said you want unique `Name` and `Age`.

Comment: `list(people.groupby(['PostalCode', 'Age']).groups)` ..?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [`Groupby.groups`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html):

```
list(people.groupby(['PostalCode', 'Age']).groups)
```

[out]

```
[('ab 11', 10), ('ab 22', 14)]
```

Comment: Great approach - I will accept your answer but the one from @AkshayNevrekar works perfectly as well.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. Happy coding

Comment: `people.groupby(['PostalCode', 'Age']).first()` will also do the same, returning result as a DataFrame.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need:

```
xyz = list(set((i,j) for i,j in zip(people["Age"], people["PostalCode"])))

print(xyz)
```

Output:

```
[(10, 'ab 11'), (14, 'ab 22')]
```