# How to convert dataframe into list of tuples with respect to category?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following problem. I would like to convert dataframe into list of tuples based on a category. See simple code below:

```py
data = {'product_id': ['5', '7', '8', '5', '30'], 'id_customer': ['1', '1', '1', '3', '3']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

#desired output is:
result = [('5', '7', '8'), ('5', '30')]
```

how can I do it please? This question did not help me: [Convert pandas dataframe into a list of unique tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029089/convert-pandas-dataframe-into-a-list-of-unique-tuple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `tuple` like:

```
print (df.groupby('id_customer', sort=False)['product_id'].agg(tuple).tolist())
print (df.groupby('id_customer', sort=False)['product_id'].apply(tuple).tolist())

print (list(df.groupby('id_customer', sort=False)['product_id'].agg(tuple)))
print (list(df.groupby('id_customer', sort=False)['product_id'].apply(tuple)))
[('5', '7', '8'), ('5', '30')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby.agg`:

```
>>> [tuple(v) for _, v in df.groupby('id_customer')['product_id']]
[('5', '7', '8'), ('5', '30')]
>>>
```